# Ubuntu Software gets into a transparent background

Tags: software-center, 20.04

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Recently I've deleted some default icons from /usr/share/icons folder. I don't know if it's related, but, since then, my Ubuntu Software gets into a transparent background.
There's a way to revert this?

Here is a screenshot:

Ubuntu Software

[image: Ubuntu Software]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same issue here on 20.04. Fixed it! Go into settings -> appearance  -> and select  something to your preference in "Window colors"

Comment: Thanks, the bug seems to be associated with the dark theme (installed by default in Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me. It's transparent regardless of theme.

Comment: Just upgraded to 20.04 today, still an issue with dark mode. selecting "light" or "standard" fixes it

Comment: I saw the issue after changing to dark mode but everything was fine after a restart.

Comment: same here. If I select a dark theme, I can see through the windows, whatever window it is; selecting a light theme, the issue goes away ...

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Software is now a Snap. Snap programs do not support nonstandard themes (meaning the ones you'd have to select with the Tweaks program rather than regular settings; --there can be similar issues with Flatpak) except ones also installed via Snap. The new Ubuntu software also no longer supports Flatpak.

What I had to do is install the packages "gnome-software" and "gnome-software-plugin-flatpak", then just stop using "Ubuntu Software" and use "Gnome Software" instead.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue 20.04 when I change the theme to any theme downloaded from gnome-look.org. The themes I have tried are compatible with the Gnome version.

Answer (score 1):

I migrated from budgie to gnome in 19.10, worked and looked how i wanted.
In 20.04 after upgrade software installer in gnome is transparent.

Feels like some theming is assumed, step outside that assumption, and software installer has no background fills.

Comment: It seems to be a theming problem. The issue is discussed in the snapcraft forum https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-snapstore-gui-has-no-background/17027/2

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem here after updating from 18.04.

I was using an old version of the Adapta Nokto theme and the `Ubuntu Software` background was transparent.

I've got a new version of the adapta theme at [gnome-look](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1351232/) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I use gnome tweak to change theme and got the same case, just

1. Kill snap process by system monitor.
2. Re apply theme by tweak.
3. Re open Ubuntu Software.

Answer (score -1):

go to terminal, and give these commands:

```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt-get install gnome-software
  sudo apt-get install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

Now you will get:
[Gnome Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6LcB.png) installed, use this instead of Ubuntu Software!
Hope it helps. (Note: This is an elaboration of @William Hood answer in the previous answers)